# Rails 4.0.5 still uses `secret.yaml`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial, which recommends using Rails 4.0.5 and update the secret token via `secret_token.rb`. The author even explicitly mentions that if I have `secret.yaml` instead of `secret_token.rb`, I should uninstall Rails 4.1.0 and install 4.0.5. I did that, yet when I run `rails new my_app` I still only have `secret.yaml`.

What should I do?

Comment: What is the output of `rails -v` in your terminal?

Comment: Okay, the answer is to restart computer... Hope this helps someone else down the line.

Comment: please write an answer below with your solution and accept it may be easier for someone to see in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future Googler, the solution is simply to restart your computer after uninstalling rails `4.1.0` and install `4.0.5`

Comment: @zrl3dx I'm using VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04 on Win 7

Comment: So did you restart Win 7 or just Ubuntu? Besides, any answer which is similar to "restart and you'll be fine" is so the-windows-way - you don't solve the actual problem, you... restart everything and hope everything works ;p